# Mi PLC no me da una IP dentro de mi red local

Tags: redes, dns

Veréis, sé que esta pregunta no tiene ninguna relación con ningún lenguaje de programación pero es un problema de redes y se que aquí tiene que haber alguien que me pueda orientar.

El caso es que hace unos meses me compré unos PLC`s para dar internet a mi ordenador de sobremesa, ya que el wifi practicamente ni llegaba. Hace poco descubrí que se puede hacer algo parecido al Steam Link con una Raspberry Pi y un programa llamado Moonlight. Tenía todo bajado e instalado en las Rasp y fue cuando me di cuenta de que mi raspberry no podía ver a mi ordenador. Configure una IP estática así como la máscara de subred y los DNS pero nada, era imposible que mi ordenador (Windows 10) viese a la Rasbperry.

cuando tenía habilitado el DHCP pude ver que me asignaba una IP extraña, y a través de https://whatismyipaddress.com/es/mi-ip me di cuenta que la IP que esta página me mostraba era la misma que mi ordenador, cuando generalmente cuando te conectas a dicha página desde un ordenador por wifi (por ejemplo) la IP que te muestra es la de tu router, pero no era el caso aquí.

Mi pregunta es, ¿puedo hacer que esa IP cambie y el DHCP me de una dirección correcta?

PD: mis PLC`s son: https://www.tp-link.com/es/products/details/cat-5034_TL-PA4010P-KIT.html

Muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Te invito a hacer la pregunta en la comunidad de [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), si no sabes inglés puedes ayudarte de un traductor ;)

Comment: usa esto para traducir de mejor manera: http://www.deepl.com/translator

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apunte, ya he realizado la pregunta en la comunidad que me habéis recomendado, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Primero descarta que los plc están mal. Conecta la raspberry directamente al router y comprueba que te dá una ip buena. 
Si es así, el problema es la configuración del plc. Resetea y vuelve al inicio, intenta actualizar firmware.